# Check which audio file is opened in MediaPlayer

Tags: android, if-statement, audio, media-player

Is there any way to programmatically know which audio file opened?
I am using an array of audio files.

My code:

```
    int[] audios = {R.raw.no, R.raw.yes};
    Random r = new Random();
    audio = MediaPlayer.create(this,audios[r.nextInt(audios.length)]);
    audio.start();
```

Check which audio had been loaded:

```
    @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.button:
            if (audio.equals(R.raw.no)) {
            text.setText("No is loaded");}
                else {text.setText("Another file is loaded");}
                break;
                 }
```

But this dont work..

Comment: please answer you question and accept it so it is not come in unanswered search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an int value for getting info about randomly opened files.

```
    int currentaudio;
    currentaudio = audios[r.nextInt(audios.length)];
```

It will output which file is loaded.